# plotting a function on a (x,y) plane

Tags: equation-solving

I looked at different questions asked concerning the error message that I get but it did not help. 
I try to plot a function. Here is the code that I use ;

```
u[c_] := (c^(1 - σ) - 1)/(1 - σ)
h[s_] := (2 hbar)/(1 + Exp[η (1 - s/sbar)])
d[s_] := (b s^2)/2
ψ[k_] := ω + (1 - ω) Exp[-γ k]
co[a_] := x  (a^2)/2
```

The calibration I use ;

```
paramFinal1 = {σ -> 2.1, ρ -> 0.01, sbar -> 128, η -> 5.1, hbar -> 0.08, b -> 0.0001, γ -> 0.6, χ -> 0.025, ω -> 0.185, δ -> 0.015, x -> 0.14, β -> 0.8};
```

I wrote the following code ;

Here is the function that I try to plot on a $(k,s)$ plane

```
l[k_, s_] :=   u'[χ/β s] - β (h'[s]/(ρ + h[s]) ((u[χ/β s] - ψ[k] d[s] - co[δ k]  )/(χ + (ρ + h[s]))) + ( ψ[k] d'[s])/(χ + (ρ + h[s])))
```

I write

```
sol3[i_] := Solve[l[k, i] == 0 /. paramFinal1, k]
tab = Table[sol3[i], {i, 1, 300}];
pollutiondot0 = Last /@ Flatten[tab] // ListPlot
```

But the code generates the following error messages ;

> Solve::inex: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact
>   coefficients or the system obtained by direct rationalization of
>   inexact numbers present in the system. Since many of the methods used
>   by Solve require exact input, providing Solve with an exact version of
>   the system may help. >>
>   General::stop: Further output of Solve::inex will be suppressed during
>   this calculation. >>

How can I fix it ? What could be the problem ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using exact numbers e.g. instead of `p -> 0.01` use `p -> 1/100`. You can use `Rationalize[]` to convert your parameters automatically.

Comment: You also might try to use `NSolve` instead of `Solve` to find a numerical solution

Comment: This is a question about Solve and NSolve, not a question about plotting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
u[c_] := (c^(1 - σ) - 1)/(1 - σ);
h[s_] := (2 hbar)/(1 + Exp[η (1 - s/sbar)]);
d[s_] := (b s^2)/2;
ψ[k_] := ω + (1 - ω) Exp[-γ k];
co[a_] := x (a^2)/2;

paramFinal1 = {σ -> 2.1, ρ -> 0.01, sbar -> 128, η -> 5.1, 
   hbar -> 0.08, b -> 0.0001, γ -> 0.6, χ -> 0.025, 
   ω -> 0.185, δ -> 0.015, x -> 0.14, β -> 0.8};

l[k_, s_] := 
  u'[χ/β s] - β (h'[
         s]/(ρ + 
          h[s]) ((u[χ/β s] - ψ[k] d[s] - 
           co[δ k])/(χ + (ρ + h[s]))) + 
           (ψ[k] d'[s])/(χ + (ρ + h[s])));
```

Use [`NSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html) and since you are using a numeric technique, restrict `sol3` to numeric arguments

```
sol3[i_?NumericQ] :=
 {i, k} /. NSolve[l[k, i] == 0 /. paramFinal1, k, Reals]
```

For many values of `i` there is a single solution, e.g.,

```
sol3[1]

(*  {{1, -22.6603}}  *)
```

However, for some values of `i` there are two solutions, e.g.,

```
sol3[100]

(*  {{100, -2.37307}, {100, 133.086}}  *)

tab = Table[sol3[i], {i, 1, 300}];

ListLinePlot[
 Flatten[#, {1}] & /@ {Last /@ tab, First /@ Select[tab, Length[#] == 2 &]},
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this insightful code.